# Error:` can't resolve `0' {.text section} in MIPS asm program

Tags: mips32

I am new for mips assembly programming ,currently i am compiling and executing mips assembly programs on android os with ndk-r8, when i compiling the following code on android os for mips core i got the following errors.

**Android.mk file**

```
  LOCAL_CFLAGS += -march=24kec -O2

** Program  **

     .set noreorder
     .text 
     .align 4
     .globl main
     .ent main 
main:      
     addiu    $4, $4,  -HIERL # lns  > HIERL

     .end main

  `Error:` can't resolve `0' {.text section} - `HIERL' {*UND* section}
```

can someone explain me how to resolve the above error.

thanks
Ajith

Comment: What is `HIERL` defined as? Is that a constant? Where's the definition?

Comment: The HIERL is a define constant which is defined in the constant.h file.i directly access this constant by constant.h included in the asm file. For example #include "constant.h"

Answer (score 0):

the MIPS doesn't suppor the  addiu    $4, $4,  -HIERL # lns  > HIERL
with negative label
you should do this with temporary register and subu

for e.x:
instead-> 
`addiu   t0, ra, -Label`
use ->

```
`addiu t0, $0, Label`
`subu t0, ra, t0`
```